# Proving positive invariance

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, mathematical-biology

I need to prove that set $D$([A picture for Set $D$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ34i.jpg)) given by
$$D=\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq L_0,~0\leq y\leq X_0,~0\leq x+y \leq R_0\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}_+^2$$ of the system:
$$\dot{x}=k_1(R_0-x-y)(L_0-x)-k_{-1}x,~\dot{y}=k_2(R_0-x-y)(X_0-y)-k_{-2}y$$
is positively invariant. I thought of checking the direction of the vector fields on the boundary of $D$ (set $D$ is a trapezium as shown in the picture) and I showed that all the vector fields point inwards except at the corner (denoted $C$) where $$\dot{x}=0,~\dot{y}<0, \text{for } x=0,~y=R_0 $$. Here, the vector field points downwards tangential to $D$. To determine what happens at this point, I thought of checking the sign of the dot product between the vector field and the normal's field. I chose the normal such that it points inside $D$ by considering $\vec{n}_C=(1,-1)$ such that:
$$(1)\cdot\dot{x}+(-1)\cdot\dot{y}$$
and by substituting $x=0,~y=R_0$, I got $$(1)\cdot\dot{x}+(-1)\cdot\dot{y}=k_{-2}y>0$$ which is positive. The positive value means that the vector fields and the normals' point in the same direct.

*Is my approach fine? If it is correct, I would like to back my reasoning with some literature/theorem. Can someone help me which theorem can I use to back up my reasoning? Is there another way in which I can show that the vector fields point inwards? I appreciate in advance.*

Comment: Your set $D$ is closed. So as long as your vector field does not actually point outward (it can be tangent at some points), $D$ is invariant. // That said, what you did with taking the inner product does not actually show what you want, precisely because $C$ is a corner: there exists vectors at $C$ pointing out of $D$ that has positive inner product with the particular normal you choose.

Comment: Thank you Willie Wong for that positive response. Is there a specific theorem that I can use to conclude that since D is closed then even if the vector field is tangential to it, it is invariant?

Comment: As for the second approach suggested (i,e, the existence of vectors pointing outwards with the positive inner product), I'm not really sure how I can make a conclusion about the vector field pointing inwards. Would kindly highlight that, please! Thank you.